# Add PHP code to a button created using Visual Composer in a woocommerce powered website

Tags: php, woocommerce, visual-composer

I have created a form using visual composer. In this form I want to assign a PHP function defined in functions.php to the submit button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You Can Do Like This**

```
// Your Shortcode to output the custom PHP in Visual Composer.
function my_vc_shortcode( $atts ) {
   // Your Custom Php Code Here 
   return '<h2>This is my custom PHP output!</h2>';
}
add_shortcode( 'my_vc_php_output', 'my_vc_shortcode');
```

> Check Source Code Here:

1. https://theremotedev.com/custom-php-code-visual-composer-pages/
2. [Insert PHP code into the Visual Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626217/insert-php-code-into-the-visual-composer)

Comment: How to associate shortcode with the form's button as there is no formal mechanism to do it

Comment: Thank you so much. Also can you help me out with client side validation in visual composer?

Comment: yaa sure.. but you can't ask two question in one, as per stackoverflow termsandcondition you have to ask a new question with problem

Comment: @AarthnaMaheshwari If You Get the ans of you first question then vote up and tick as a right

Comment: @AarthnaMaheshwari ..its can help you for validation on client side .... https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/b0969ff9-e0b3-2b10-fe9e-80509bfda414/DataValid_1224200835016AM_v2.pdf

Comment: @AarthnaMaheshwari If Get The Ans Then Vote Up Please.. :)